# Are "functions" a fundamental part of the x86 hardware?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

On the popular x86 architecture, execution flow can be controlled with one of the `jmp`-type instructions, as well as with the `call` instruction. But are both fundamental, or is one "syntactic sugar" for the other?

For example, the `push` instruction is syntactic sugar: `push eax` is equivalent to `mov [esp], eax` followed by `sub esp, 4`. So `mov` is the only *fundamental* data operation.

But is this also the case for `call`? Is there some other set of instructions that achieves the same?

In pseudo-code, I *could* write a function call with `jmp` if I had access to the 
instruction pointer:

```asm
bar:
    push eip    ;; pseudo-code!              ;; call foo
    jmp foo

foo:
    pop eax                                  ;; ret
    jmp [eax]
```

This isn't valid x86, since the instruction pointer register `eip` cannot be read directly. And all "tricks" I've seen so far that obtain the value of `eip` all use `call`. Or is `call` in fact the *canonical* way to read the instruction pointer on x86? As a bonus question, does every architecture on which C can be implemented require a way to read the instruction pointer, so that function pointers can be implemented?

```c
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int (*p)() = strtoul(argv[1]);

    return p();                     // how to implement without
                                    // accessing the instruction pointer?
}
```

[This isn't a deep question; I would simply find it emotionally gratifying to know that functions are not just an abstraction introduced by high-level programming languages, but actually hardware-intrinsic.]

Comment: The `push` instruction is NOT syntactic sugar -- yes it has the same net effect as a longer sequence of instructions, but the time required to execute is different.  There is an actual different sequence of instruction bits involved.  Syntactic sugar generally refers to something that will generate the exact same machine code bit pattern, such as the `nop` instruction, which is the same as `xchg eax,eax`

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Very interesting, thanks! Feel free to expand on that in an answer!

Comment: There's `lea reg, [rip]` in 64bit mode btw. Actually `push eax` is not typically implemented as `mov [esp], eax \ sup esp, 4`, but by special trickery that makes the esp-adjustment take no time (it does however take a special re-synchronization operation when you then use `esp` the normal way). Typically anyway.

Comment: @harold: Yes, I noticed that x86_64 seems to allow this -- why was that made legal? It's a weird little change...

Comment: It makes position-independence easier (as long as the data and code are moved as one thing) and it prevents almost all cases where you need to have 64bit constant addresses in the code (which would take annoyingly many bytes to encode), but I couldn't say for sure why AMD added it

Comment: [Only one instruction is fundamental](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer). Any computation can be implemented using just a subtract-and-branch-if-negative instruction.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'm not sure that one is even fundamental.  I'd expect that "add-and-branch-if-positive" probably would work, too.  The excuse for doing subtract instead of add can be found :-} in the Unisys 1108 series of mainframes, which doesn't internally have *adders*, it has subtractors, because the logic to subtract-bit-from-bit-and-propagate-borrow is weirdly one or two gates cheaper than the logic to add-bit-to-bit-and-propagate-carry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Machine instructions sets could be pretty trivial; see [Wolfram's 2-state, 3 symbol Turing machine.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfram%27s_2-state_3-symbol_Turing_machine) The problem is that such machines are hard to program and hard to make run fast.

You can completely simulate call return with other instructions:

```
    ;  Simulate "call abc":
    push    offset next_location
    jmp     abc
 next_location:

    ; Simulate "ret"
    pop    eax
    jmp    eax
```

You can obviously simulate the push/pops with mov instructions and adjusting registers by adding constants as you noted in your question.

People add instructions to an instruction set to make common sequences efficient.  Thus, "call" exists because it does a commonly useful task (and "call/ret" pairs can be optimized by hardware using an internal stack of return addresses to avoid instruction pipeline breaks; this is a real performance win).

So, yes, you could use a smallest set of instructions offered by a computer to achieve your assembly language purposes.  But the *right* additional instructions really help in practice.  (You can, with good intent, add instructions you think might be useful. Often they don't help, this is the [source of the original RISC/CISC debate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing)).

Goofball minimal machines:

- There was real minicomputer ("GRI") produced in the 1970s that had only one instruction: MOV LOC1 to LOC2; the target locations were magic and that's how real work got done.  By moving something to location 33 (made up), a sideffect was that the value was added to an accumulator that could be read from location 32.   It had lots of locations that did funny, convenient things, so in essence adding a new funny register is just a strange variant of adding useful instructions.  I suspect JMP instructions consisted of moving a constant to the location that acted as the program counter.  (If this seem strange to you, you haven't met a PDP-11).
- A theory machine is one with the single instruction  "SUB LOC1 from LOC2 jmp to LOC3 if negative".   This machine is universal but not fun to program after your first toy problem.

It is interesting to note that both of these instructions sets have no opcode bits or addresssing mode bits.  The instruction decoder is simple, indeed.

Comment: By the way, there seem to be instructions `enter`/`leave` for "common sequences", but they don't seem to be used by GCC. (By the way, I'm somewhat familiar with the theory machine. Good point.)

Comment: "enter"/"leave" turn out to be one of those "gee, this seems useful" that turned out to be not so useful in practice.  A perfect example of useless CISC, but now permanently built into Intel instructions set, permanently using a little bit of extra power.

Comment: A bit of the reason that enter/leave aren't used (by GCC) is that they support languages with nested lexical scopes.. which C and C++ don't do, IIRC.  That by itself doesn't make them bad.  My company builds a compiler which *does* have lexical scopes and these instructions initially seemed attractive.  It turns out they don't quite do *exactly* what our compiler needed, and so we generate something else which is fast enough.   So they failed to be useful in exactly the circumstances they were needed; this is a common failure of complex instructions and the reason not to add them.

Comment: enter/leave are also pretty slow in current processors.  Back in the day there was occasion to use them sometimes, but now they're not terribly useful (but must be retained for compatibility).

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch: Are they slower than the equivalent assembly instructions?  If so, they've become vestigial.  I'd expect them to be limited by memory accesses since enter is about copying a (dense) display (array of pointers to outer lexical scope blocks).  One reason we don't use them is that as a practical matter, you don't have to copy the entire display for many lexically scoped procedures, and what you don't copy reduces function call overhead.